# Analogue of Fubini's theorem for product space between natural numbers and an arbitrary measure space

Tags: measure-theory

This is the last part of Bartle's "Elements of Integration" exercise 10.J.

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ be a measure space, and consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Let $(Z = \mathbb{N} \times X, \mathcal{B}, \pi)$ be the product of the beforementioned measure spaces.

If $f: Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function, and $f_n$ are its $n$-sections ($f_n: X \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x) = f(n, x))$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I need to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_X f_n d \nu\right) = \int_X \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n\right)d\nu$$

I tried finding an integrable function that dominates $\sum f_n$, and got nowhere. Also tried to prove first for nonnegative functions, and using the definition of the integral for arbitrary function, but to no avail. Could anyone give me some hint?

Comment: How is this different from just being a special case of exactly Fubini's theorem (along with the statement that both sides are equal to $\int_Z f \,d\pi$)?

Comment: Fubini's theorem requires that the measures you are taking the product be $\sigma$-finite. In this case, $\nu$ is an arbitrary measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-negative integrable $f$ this follows by Monotone Convergence Theorem: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f_k$ increases to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k$ as $n$ increases to $\infty$. For the general case use the decomposition $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$.